# JsPlumb - Remove state machine's self connection without using 'detach'

Tags: connection, state-machine, jsplumb

I am looking for solution to remove state machine's self connection. By self-connection, I mean the connection to itself.

On Jsplumb website, connections are removed on clicking it. I am performing some other action on onclick of connection so I would like to have some other option for removing this connection specifically in self connection situation.

In other case, where there is connection between two separate states, I am able to remove connection just by dragging arrow of connection away from the state. This can be tried on http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/statemachine/jquery.html.
For self connection it is not possible to drag arrow point.

I tried to search why this is happening in jsPlumb (version 1.4) js file.. I found that for self connection it doesn't add class '_jsPlumb_endpoint_full' i.e. it doesn't add endpoint at arrow while for connection between two states it adds this class for arrow point.

Can somebody please suggest me or at least provide a hint on this ?